# How to disable resolving of un-registered types in simpleInjector?

Tags: dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am trying to use SimpleInjector as DI Container for NServiceBus. While trying to do so, i ran into a problem caused with resolving of un-registered types. I need to make sure that un-registered types are not resolved by SimpleInjector.

I did try below code, however it didn't do any good.

```
_context.ResolveUnregisteredType += _context_ResolveUnregisteredType;

 void _context_ResolveUnregisteredType(object sender,    
                                          UnregisteredTypeEventArgs e)
    {
       e.Register(()=> null);
    }
```

Any ideas/suggestions welcome.

Comment: What do you exactly want? Do you want an exception to be thrown in case an unregistered concrete type is resolved? Can you give a bit more context for your question? Why do you actually need this?

Comment: Context: NServiceBus version:4.4.2.
Depending features enabled in NServiceBus, types are initialized and registered with DI Container for further usage. (ex: CriticalTimeCounter). When features are disabled, types are not initialized and not even registered with DI Container.

However, SimpleInjector is trying to resolve un-registered types which are not initialized. Hence, causing null reference issues with-in. Due to which, i would like to disable resolving on un-registered types.

Comment: So what is the behavior you expect from Simple Injector? Throw an exception when such type is resolved?

Comment: You can call the container's `GetService` method (by casting to `IServiceProvider`). This will return null for unregistered/unresolvable types.

Comment: I only wanted to get null for unregistered types. Could you tell me where should I call GetService method?

Comment: public class Class1
{
    public Class2 SomeProperty {get; set;}
}

In above code, Class1 is registered and Class2 is not registered. When Class1 is resolved, i want SomeProperty to be not set.

Comment: Ahhh, you want to do [implicit property injection](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#property-injection).

Comment: Yes. I want to avoid resolution of Class2, even when it is constructor parameter.

Comment: Read the referenced documentation. I suggest staying away from implicit property injection completely because of the reasons described in the docs.

Comment: Even if I want to use constructor injection, un-registered dependencies are resolved automatically. Is there a way to prevent this SimpleInjector.?

Comment: It's impossible to inject `null` values into constructors. Please reconsider your design. Instead of injecting `null`, inject [Null Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). Null Objects are default empty implementations that are registered in the container when a 'real' implementation is missing.

Comment: Ok. This is the only feature, that is stopping me from integrating with NServiceBus. Is there any possibility that SimpleInjector can make resolution of un-registered types as optional feature?

Comment: It's impossible to inject `null` values into constructors, but you can do implicit property injection as explained [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility.html#overriding-property-injection-behavior) (see the `ImplicitPropertyInjectionBehavior` example). Still, my advice stands: Prevent doing implicit property injection (ever! not only with Simple Injector) but make sure dependencies are never optional (for instance by using Null Objects).